# Python OpenCV Trackbar Error For cv2.getTrackbarPos

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, visual-studio-code, trackbar

I'm attempting to execute the following Python 3.9.5 script using Visual Studio Code on a Windows 10 PC:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)


def empty(a):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow("HSV")
cv2.resizeWindow("HSV", 640, 240)
cv2.createTrackbar("HUE MIN", "HSV", 0, 179, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("HUE Max", "HSV", 129, 129, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("SAT Min", "HSV", 0, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("SAT Max", "HSV", 255, 255 ,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("VALUE Min", "HSV", 0, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("VALUE Max", "HSV", 255, 255, empty)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid1.mp4')
frameCounter = 0

while True:
    frameCounter +=1
    if cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) == frameCounter:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
        frameCounter=0

    _, img = cap.read()
    imgHsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("HUE Min", "HSV")
    h_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("HUE Max", "HSV")
    s_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("SAT Min", "HSV")
    s_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("SAT Max", "HSV")
    v_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("VALUE Max", "HSV")
    v_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("VALUE Max", "HSV")
    print(h_min)

    lower = np.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
    upper = np.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHsv, lower, upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    hstack = np.hstack([img, mask, result])
    cv2.imshow('Horizontal Stacking', hstack)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.waitKey(0)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, upon execution, I get the following error:

```
[ WARN:0@0.229] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:...\ColorPickerScript.py", line 35, in <module>
    h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("HUE Min", "HSV")
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:862: error: (-215:Assertion failed) trackbar in function 'cv::getTrackbarPos'
```

I was hoping someone could point me in the correct direction to figure out why this is happening and what I can do to fix it. I haven't been able to find any solutions yet, thanks!

Comment: you made a typo. all-caps in one string, not in the other. -- I agree, the assertion is cryptic. feel free to open an issue about this on opencv's github. the issue is that `trackbar` (in the opencv code) is NULL because no trackbar with the given name could be found. point to this question for context and post a link to the issue here.

Comment: and you copied that code wrong. `if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):` is wrong. `and` is a boolean operator, but a bitwise operator was intended. just remove the entire `and 0xFF` because it's redundant. the same thing is already done inside of `waitKey`. you're following ancient advice or the teacher is an amateur.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by Christoph Rackwitz, the problem was that I made a type, where I had one string in all caps but not the other. Correcting this fixed the issue.

Comment: Questions about problems caused by a typo are off-topic. Do not post answers to off-topic questions, even if they're your own.

Comment: You should try using a comment or editiing your question next time instead of an answer to provide more information.